# How do I apply 'background-image: cover;' to this awesome HTML5 'drag and drop' demo?

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, background-image

I am trying to follow this demo: http://html5demos.com/file-api

It works perfect - exactly what I want, except for when the file is larger than the image area.

I need the image to resize, maintaining the aspect ratio. In other examples, I have found that applying the CSS 'background-image: cover;' is exactly what I want.

But, I can't seem to figure out how to make that work with this demo.

Ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this example you can add to the Div with the ID `holder`:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-size: cover;
```

It is not `background-image` it is `background-size`.